# What's the simplest way to remove a filter with Google Sheets Script, that doesn't pop out an error if there's no active filters at the moment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I managed to automate some calculations with barely any coding experience, but I've hit a snag.

I've been using the code:

```
spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Formulas & Data').getFilter().remove();
```

but it doesn't work if there's no active filter in the sheet.

I need an `if` function so the above code is executed only if there is an active filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Check if filter is currently applied before removing it.

---

#### Code:

```
function removeFilter() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var filter = sh.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
}
```

As you can see, we define the filter in `var filter`, then check if it exists in the `if` statement. If the statement returns `true`, the filter will be removed, if `false`, do nothing.

---

#### References:

- [JavaScript `if` Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- [`getFilter()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfilter)
- [`filter.remove()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#remove())